# GCP DL Image instance automatically starts Jupyter server but I cant find login Token

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-dl-platform

I just created a VM instance with deep-learning-vm image provided by GCP.  I am trying remote access to notebook server. However I realized jupyter notebook server starts the moment I start the VM. I can use the `external_ip:8888` to connect the VM's jupyter notebook server.

There is 1 issue with his. Normally when we start jupyter notebook server manually it provides us a login token. In this case I do not know what the token is.

Second issue is when i do `jupyter notebook list` to see running servers, i see nothing. I tried with `sudo` user as well. There is no trace of a running server. However I can connect to login page of jupyter server regardless. Also when i check the ports using `lsof -i`, I can see jupyter is listening even tho I did not started it manually.

i tried to to kill the ports but they start again after seconds. I dont understand how I am suppose to use the jupyter server without token information. I tried to setup a password but it did not worked.

I tried changing the user, killing the ports, manually running the server using `jupyter-lab`. However these did not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some assumptions that need clarification.

1. When you use Deep Learning Platform, Jupyter is a dedicated `systemctl` service. The Jupyter service is defined here: `/lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service`

You can access JupyterLab through a Proxy URL provided by Google.
Jupyter Service binds to local IP address (127.0.0.1) and port (8080) and does not use a token.

To track Jupyter status use: `systemctl status jupyter.service`

Example:

```
/lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Notebook Service

[Service]
Type=simple
MemoryHigh=15348914432
MemoryMax=15398914432
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/timeout 60 sh -c 'while ! ss -t -l -n sport = :8080 | grep -q "^LISTEN.*:8080"; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=/bin/bash --login -c '/opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --config=/home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py'
User=jupyter
Group=jupyter
WorkingDirectory=/home/jupyter
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Is a not a good security practice to start JupyterLab manually and use an external IP address. This is why we provide a Proxy URL or recommend SSH access.
3. You can explore User Managed Notebooks which uses the same underlying OS as the Deep Learning VM image:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/create-new

https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/cli